# Property or field cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I run Junit test it retrieves the data from NASA's api and gives me list of JSON objects. When I try to use thymeleaf and spring boot it fails to list images and data as well. Trying to learn spring boot, but stuck with this exception.

This is my html:

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Mars Rover API App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Welcome to the Mars Rover API Web App</h2>
        
    <img th:each="photo : ${roverData.photos}" th:src="${photo.imgSrc}" />   
  </body>
</html>
```

Api response class:

```java
public class RoverApiResponse {
    private List<MarsPhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public List<MarsPhoto> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(List<MarsPhoto> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "MarsRoverApiResponse [photos=" + photos + "]";
    }
}
```

Api Service:

```java
@Service
public class MarsRoverApiService {
    private final String API_DEMO_LINK= "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=2&api_key=DEMO_KEY"; 

    public String getAPI_DEMO_LINK() {
        return API_DEMO_LINK;
    }

    public RoverApiResponse getRoverData() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<RoverApiResponse> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(getAPI_DEMO_LINK(), RoverApiResponse.class);
        
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

MarsPhoto class:

```java
public class MarsPhoto {
    private Long id;
    private Integer sol;
    private Camera camera;

    @JsonProperty("img_src")
    private String imgSrc;

    @JsonProperty("earth_date")
    private Date earthDate;

    private Rover rover;
    
    public Date getEarthDate() {
        return earthDate;
    }
    
    public void setEarthDate(Date earthDate) {
        this.earthDate = earthDate;
    }
    
    public Rover getRover() {
        return rover;
    }
    
    public void setRover(Rover rover) {
        this.rover = rover;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Integer getSol() {
        return sol;
    }
    
    public void setSol(Integer sol) {
        this.sol = sol;
    }
    
    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }
    
    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
    }
    
    public String getImgSrc() {
        return imgSrc;
    }
    
    public void setImgSrc(String imgSrc) {
        this.imgSrc = imgSrc;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MarsPhoto [id=" + id + ", sol=" + sol + ", camera=" + camera + ", imgSrc=" + imgSrc + ", earthDate=" + earthDate + ", rover=" + rover + "]";
    }
}
```

This is HomeController where I map index.html

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private MarsRoverApiService apiService;

    public MarsRoverApiService getApiService() {
        return apiService;
    }
    
    public void setApiService(MarsRoverApiService apiService) {
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String renderHomePage(ModelMap model) {
        RoverApiResponse roverData = apiService.getRoverData();
        
        model.put("roverData", roverData);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

This is the exception message I get:

```java
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")] with root cause
    org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'photos' cannot be found on null
```

Comment: Where do you set `roverData` which is used in your HTML? It is still `null`

Comment: I edited the question and added Controller class where I set roverData

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as it's written, appears to be correct.  I would suggest that you add a breakpoint on this line in your service.  Verify that after this executes, you have a response that contains data.

```
ResponseEntity<RoverApiResponse> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(getAPI_DEMO_LINK(), RoverApiResponse.class);
```

You can add a couple of assertions after this to validate:

```
assert response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatusCode.valueOf(200);
assert response.getBody() != null;
```

Comment: It throws exception at that line.

Comment: well, that explains why it's null.  So, what is the exception that's thrown from that line?

Comment: SpelEvaluationException and TemplateProcessingException

Comment: There's no way THAT line can throw those exceptions.  Add a breakpoint to the line indicated and evaluate that line and only that line.  The response from the API is null, which is why everything else is failing.